# positioned in stack error when keyboard is open

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]
[image]

I have this component, but when I open a keyboard I have this error.

This is my code:

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: Dimension.paddingXL),
                      child: TextField(),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - Dimension.paddingXL,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3 * 1.7,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: AppColors.whiteLogin,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(Dimension.borderRadiusLogin))),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 130.0,
                child: Container(
                  height: 110,
                  width: 110,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(width: 9, color: Colors.red),
                      color: AppColors.whiteLogin,
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(Dimension.borderRadiusAll))),
                  child: Icon(
                    Remix.user_3_line,
                    size: 45,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

I'd rather have all the content go up once the keyboard is open or or the prettiest visual solution.
I tried with SingleChildScrollView but don't work for me!

How I can solve this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Stack Widget should be placed in a constrained layout in order to scroll its children when they receive focus. When Textfield receives focus it gets scrolled outside of Parent Container child. So to solve this you can place Stack Widget inside a SizedBox widget and give it a static height so UI is scrolled along with child elements.

Refer this Youtube Video Link for better understanding:

[Youtube Video Link Explaining the Solution to this Proble](https://youtu.be/2m3NcGEwxFM)

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100, left: 10, right: 10),
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 400,
            child: Stack(
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 10,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3 * 1.7,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      // color: AppColors.whiteLogin,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          // Radius.circular(Dimension.borderRadiusLogin)
                          Radius.circular(20)
                          )),
                  child: Column(
                    children: const [
                      Padding(
                        // padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: Dimension.paddingXL),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 80, left: 20, right: 20),
                        child: TextField(),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  // top: 130.0,
                  top: -50,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 110,
                    width: 110,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(width: 9, color: Colors.red),
                        // color: AppColors.whiteLogin,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(
                              // Dimension.borderRadiusAll
                              60
                              ))),
                    child: const Icon(
                      // Remix.user_3_line,
                      Icons.person,
                      size: 45,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Scaffold` widget, try setting `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to false.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).